# Can I assert that jagged array is equivalent to the other one in NUnit framework?

Tags: c#, nunit, jagged-arrays

In [C#'s NUnit framework](https://nunit.org/) there is `Is.EquivalentTo` constraint which can be very useful for asserting that two arrays are equivalent in the "permutation" way, (i.e. order of the elements does not matter, only the content.)

E.g. the following test will pass

```
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            Assert.That(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, Is.EquivalentTo(new[] { 2, 3, 1 }));
        }
```

I have been thinking, is there any way to apply the same constraints for jagged arrays?
I would like to do the following

```
        [Test]
        public void Test2D()
        {
            // expected true, but fails
            Assert.That(new[] { new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2, 3 } }, Is.EquivalentTo(new[] { new[] { 3, 2 }, new[] { 1 } }));
        }
```

Comment: Those are not  two dimensional arrays, those are [jagged ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13188088/10713658) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2893297/10713658).

Comment: @MarianoLuisVilla These threads do not resolve my issue. Could you clarify it?

Comment: Apologies, my point was to iterate and compare. I don't know how much of a concern is performance, but you could (pseudocode): `Assert.That(A2.Any(x => x.Sorted() == eachArrayInA1.Sorted())`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example won't work because of the definition of equivalence in NUnit.

NUnit takes two enumerables (in this case the outer arrays) and checks that the contents are equal *without respect to order*.

So this will pass:

```cs
Assert.That(new[] { new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2, 3 } },
    Is.EquivalentTo(new[] { new[] { 2, 3 }, new[] { 1 } }));
```

Your example OTOH fails because you want equivalence to apply to the individual items in the collection as well as the collection itself.

As has been pointed out, you could define your own equality comparer and apply it with the `.Using()` modifier. That's what I would do in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I guess for my purpose I will sort the inner arrays using LINQ and then use the standard `Is.EquivalentTo()`, best.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the all contributions.

I would like to present my approach for the problem.
I simply sort the inner arrays, and then use `Is.EquivalentTo()`

```cs
        [Test]
        public void Test2D()
        {
            var actual = new[] { new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2, 3 } }
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(e => e));

            var expected = new[] { new[] { 3, 2 }, new[] { 1 } }
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(e => e));

            Assert.That(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
        }
```