# How do I Transpose a multi dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I think this might be a pretty simple question, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. If I've got a 2-dimensional array like so:

```
int[,] matris = new int[5, 8] { 
       { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8 }, 
       {9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},
       { 17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 },
       { 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32 },
       { 33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40 },

        };
```

and a for loop, like this:

```
  for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                Console.Write("{0} ", matris[r, j]);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

So with this code I am printing out the multi dimensional array. But how do I print out a transpose of the array?

Comment: What do you mean by "transponent"? It's not a term I've come across before.

Comment: Can you define _transponent_?

Comment: Perhaps he means transpose? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: EDIT: sorry guys, i meant transpose

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2893367/2630934  They talk about multi dimensional arrays, but to transpose an array of [x,y], you just have to make a new array with dimensions [y,x] and assign to each individual value accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

Just change your loops with each other:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
        Console.Write("{0} ", matris[r, j]);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Creating new array:

```
var newArray = new int[8, 5];
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
        newArray[j, r] = matris[r, j];
```

Comment: yeeah ok now I see what I did wrong.. But if I want to save the transpose matris into an new array?

Answer (score 10):

You just need to do this:

```
for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        Console.Write("{0} ", matris[j, r]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: oh, posted too late! It's pretty much the same solution that @MarcinJuraszek posted :)

Comment: I would say this is the right answer. People just rush into up-voting.

Comment: @ataravati It's exactly the same as mine :) Just variables names replaced.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It is exactly the same, but you have switched the variables in the original question, which may give the wrong impression (to the beginners) that two sets of loops are required to achieve this. And, your comment is actually misleading too.