# Looping though jagged array while fixing some dimentions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, jagged-arrays

I have a 7 dimensional jagged array that essentially is just a collection of decimal numbers. I need to go through the array and add up all the decimals that have certain values in certain columns. For example;

```
(A)(B)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)
```

Where .. is the entire size of the dimention. For the above case I can simply use a bunch of nested for loops because I know that A and B are at the start of the array. But how can I deal with this if the dimention in which A and B are located is randomised. Eg.

```
(..)(A)(..)(..)(B)(..)(..)
Or
(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(A)(B)
Or
(..)(..)(A)(..)(..)(..)(B)
Etc.
```

I thought about have a select case for the locations of A and B but this leads to hundreds (if not thousands) of lines of repeated code, and it feels like bad practice.

Any suggestions?

**Edit #1**
This is difficult to explain so I'm going to use a much more simple example. Instead of 7 dimentions let's say it's 2 dimentions (each with a length of 4). And instead of A and B let's say it's just A. I wish to add the following elements:

```
(A)(0)
(A)(1)
(A)(2)
(A)(3)
(0)(A)
(1)(A)
(2)(A)
(3)(A)
```

As you can see this is every element where A is in either of the dimentions (A is a real number, in this case either 0, 1, 2, or 3). Now in my case there's the need for *both* A and B to be in one of the dimentions **and** the requirement that A is always before B. But since there's 7 dimentions there's so many possible locations of A and B that writing code to each scenario is not ideal (also I'd like to extend it to C, D, etc.)

Comment: `Recursion`   ???

Comment: 7 dimensional? Or an array with 7 elements?

Comment: I'm sure recursion is the answer. I just don't know how to sort it!

Comment: 7 dimensional. In total (across all dimentions) there's roughly 100 million elements.

Comment: Is it [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51922659/7444103)? There, is calculated the average of the *vertical* values of a jagged array. The comparison here is between two arrays of values extended along the *vertical* dimension, if I have understood your requirements.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. Sum the content of your collections? And, if so, do you need to keep these summations handy, or is it just an output?

Comment: I'll edit the question to add more detail.

Comment: Better, but still kinda fuzzy. Could you describe in therms of "here's the input or starting situation" "here I have to make some treatment" "here's the desired result"?

Comment: Do you need to "find" A and B, to "insert" A and B, to "count" A and B, to... i'm not sure.