# How to sum elements of unknown number of arrays using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of numeric arrays of same sizes. Is it possible to calculate sum of their 1st, 2nd, ..., n-th elements without using for-loops?

This is my code that does it using loops:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();
    int n = 4;
    list.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    list.Add(new int[] { 5, 6, 6, 7 });
    list.Add(new int[] { 8, 9, 10, 11 });

    int[] sum = new int[n];
    foreach (int[] array in list)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum[i] += array[i];
    foreach (int value in sum)
        Console.Write($"{value} ");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: `var sum = list.SelectMany(ar => ar).Sum(v => v);`, maybe? (Written here, not tested.)

Comment: @Jimi It sums everything and returns an int.

Comment: Ah, right, you want the *vertical* sums. To add to the answer you already have, a `Enumerable.Range` one: `var sums = Enumerable.Range(0, list[0].Length).Select(col => list.Sum(lst => lst[col]));`. Only working on arrays of the same size. For arrays of different sizes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51922659/7444103).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var sum = list[0].Select((value, i) => list.Sum(sublist => sublist[i]));
```

Needs special handling for empty `list`.

Explanation:

```
sublist => sublist[i]
```

Given a `sublist` (i.e. one of the arrays), this selects the `i`-th element.

```
list.Sum(sublist => sublist[i])
```

This query calculates a single number, which is the sum of all `i`-th elements of the sublists of `list`.

```
list[0].Select((value, i) => list.Sum(sublist => sublist[i]))
```

This selects a number for each entry in `list[0]`. The number is the sum of all `i`-th entries in the sublists.

Comment: Thanks Nico, but I don't really understand how it works! Can you explain it? More specifically, how it accesses other items of list than its first array?

Comment: Added an explanation.