# c# unable to cast object of type 'system.int16[*]' to type 'system.Int16[]'

Tags: c#, opc

I am reading the values from plc tags

```
public void synch_read() //reads device
{
    Array values;
    Array errors;
    object qualities = new object(); //opc server will store the quality of the item 
    object timestamps = new object(); //store the timestamp of the read

    //read directly from device
    oGroup.SyncRead((short)OPCAutomation.OPCDataSource.OPCDevice, 2, ref handles, out values, out errors, out qualities, out timestamps);

     String abcd = (Int16[])qualities.ToString();
}
```

In this line

```
String abcd = ((Int16[])qualities).ToString();
```

I am getting the error

```
unable to cast object of type 'system.int16[*]' to type 'system.Int16[]'
```

How can I solve this error?

EDIT

I tried

```
Int16[] abcd = (Int16[2])qualities;
```

error `; expected`

Comment: You're casting to a string, then an `Int16[]` then assigning that value to a string??

Comment: `((Int16[])qualities).ToString()` too giving the same error!

Comment: @CarbineCoder, `dynamic` library not present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system.int16[*]` is a multidimensional array, not a single dimensional array.

```
Array array = (Array)qualities;
int dimensions = array.Rank;
```

If `dimensions` is 2, then it is a `int[,]`. If it is 3 it is `int[,,]` and so on.

For iterating the array with `foreach` see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893367/613130